# How to iterate gradle dependencies in custom gradle plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I have followed this guide:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

to create a standalone gradle plugin with the following structure/files:

```
  my-gradle-plugin
    > src
     > main
      > java
       > com
        > mygroup
         > MyGradlePlugin.groovy
    > build.gradle
    > settings.gradle
```

**build.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
  groovy localGroovy()
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

**MyGradlePlugin.groovy** :

```
package com.mygroup

import org.gradle.api.*

class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    print " project.name " + project.name + "\n"
    print " project.dependencies " + project.dependencies + "\n"
     // How do we iterate each dependency and print artifactId, group, version??
     // project.dependencies.each {
     //        compile(it) {
     //        print it.next()
     //        print it.name
     //      }
     //    }
   project.configurations.each {
  print it.dump()

}
   }
  }
```

In another project I use/apply this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath group: 'com.mygroup', name: 'my-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
}



dependencies {
  compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.4'
  compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.7.0'
}

install.doLast {
 apply plugin: 'my-gradle-plugin'

}
```

But how do I iterate the commons dependencies from the apply method in **MyGradlePlugin.groovy** and print their coordinates (artifactId, groupId, version)?

Comment: I assume you want to iterate through all dependencies of the configuration `compile`?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but since there is not a selected answer I'll throw in an example that I have used. This is based on the example in section 49.8.2.2 of the gradle docs.

I'm using it to do custom dependency resolution, but you can do whatever you'd like inside the dependency iteration. Note that this works because its passing a closure that is executed after the configuration phase.

Plugin code:

```
package com.overtherainbow

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencyResolveDetails

class DefaultVersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    // This is where dependency versions are defined
    def defaultVersionsMap = [
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api' : '2.5',
        'log4j:log4j' : '1.2.16']

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
                DependencyResolveDetails details -> resolveDependencyVersion(project, details)
            }
        }
    }

    def resolveDependencyVersion(Project project, DependencyResolveDetails details) {
        if (details.requested.version == 'default') {
            def version = resolveDefaultVersion(project, details.requested.group, details.requested.name)
            details.useVersion version
        }
    }

    def resolveDefaultVersion(Project project, String group, String name) {
        project.logger.debug("Resolving default dependency for $group:$name")
        println "Resolving default dependency for $group:$name"
        defaultVersionsMap["$group:$name"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that dependency graph is only available after project is fully evaluated. That's why you can't rely on that directly in the `apply` method. You have to postpone the execution using the `afterEvaluate` method. The following code will do the trick:

```
class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    project.afterEvaluate {
      println "  Project:" + project.name
      project.configurations.each { conf ->
        println "    Configuration: ${conf.name}"
        conf.allDependencies.each { dep ->
          println "      ${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**: Following question updates and discussions in the comments and chat you can also do the following:

```
class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    project.tasks.findByName('install')?.doLast {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It works if I DON'T do it in the 'afterEvaluate' scope. The plugin is now applied as the last step (after install): install.doLast {
      apply plugin: 'my-gradle-plugin'



}

Comment: The code in the answer works, I tested it with gradle 1.2. In your case with install.doLast, I would say, that's a bit weird plugin usage, if you really only needed to print out dependency list after install task, then you could just place the code into doLast, why using plugin for that?

Comment: The motivation for this is that multiple projects needs to apply this plugin and I don't want to duplicate the code for all those projects. Putting it into a plugin makes it possible to only write the script once.

Comment: yes, but Gradle plugin system is advanced enough to avoid special tricks like " call apply on the plugin only in install.onLast to get this common feature ". You can define that required behavior inside your plugin's apply method and postpone evaluation to the point it is needed. Btw. In your original question question it wasn't clear you wanted to print out dependencies as the last step of the build.

Comment: You can use gradle.buildFinished closure to define any special behaviour you want: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#buildFinished(groovy.lang.Closure).

Comment: And you can call gradle.buildFinished within your plugin as well, inside apply method

Comment: This sounds cool! But I don't want to run the plugin after the build has finished. I needs to be run after install but before eg. uploadArchives.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19145/discussion-between-u123-and-andrey-adamovich)