# Get right dependencies name in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle, build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: LolPlugin

class LolPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public void apply(Project p) {
    p.buildscript.dependencies.each {
      println it
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, you can try to get dependencies name inside custom plugin class.
But it's different between contents of output and the expected .
I expect that,

> 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

But output is

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesHandler_Decorate@174b0a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost duplicate of this question: [How to iterate gradle dependencies in custom gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202522/how-to-iterate-gradle-dependencies-in-custom-gradle-plugin)

Short answer:

```
class LolPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public void apply(Project p) {
    p.buildscript.configurations.each {
     it.allDependencies.each {
        println "${it.group}:${it.name}:${it.version}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```